# On click Windows Location not adding to form action

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, onclick, action

I am looking over a website that works in all other browsers except IE.

Is there a reason why a link like below will not work in IE?

**Code:**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/cart/add/<?php echo base64_url_encode(url_req()); ?>/" method="post">
                <div style="height: 150px;"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/product/details/<?php echo $c->getId(); ?>/"><?php if($im = Shop_image::retrieveByPk($c->getCover_image_id())) echo '<img src="',base_url(),$im->getMedium_path(),'" alt="click to read more" style="max-height: 120px; max-width: 120px;" />'; ?></a></div>
                <p style="height: 30px;"><a class="products_name" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/product/details/<?php echo $c->getId(); ?>/"><?php echo $c->getName(); ?></a></p>
                <p><span class="price"><?php if($s=Shop_special::retrieveByCatalogId($c->getId())): echo '<small><del>$', number_format($c->getPrice_net()*1.15,2),'</del></small> '; ?>$<?php echo number_format($s->getNew_price()*1.15,2); ?><?php else: ?><?php if(count($cheap=Shop_quantity_price::retrieveByCatalogIdCheapest($c->getId()))!=0): ?>From $<?php echo number_format($cheap[0]->getPrice_per_item()*1.15,2); else: ?>$<?php echo number_format($c->getPrice_net()*1.15,2); ?><?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?></span><span class="currency">&nbsp;NZD</span></p>
                <p><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/product/details/<?php echo $c->getId(); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/button_more.jpg" > &nbsp;</a>

                    <input type="hidden" name="catalog" value="<?php echo base64_url_encode($c->getId()); ?>" /><input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/button_buynow.jpg" onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/product/details/<?php echo $c->getId(); ?>/'" value="Buy Now" /></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: Why are you using a server side image map loaded up with JavaScript in the first place? What's wrong with a regular image contained in a regular link?

Comment: @Quentin I once again have been called into fix other peoples issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a JavaScript guru, so I don't know exactly why your link fails in IE. But I can offer a fix to enable your website to work without JavaScript (which might also solve your problem):

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com.au/shop/product/details/31/">
  <img src="http://www.domain.com.au/assets/images/button_buynow.jpg" alt="Buy Now" />
</a>
```

Note the standard `<a>` link, and the image within it. This does work - clicking the image activates the link.

Answer (score 0):

Because your IE is blocking your file content. Check your IE status bar. You need to click it to allow your content to run.

1 permanent solution is this >> http://www3.bpmmicro.com/web/helpandsupport.nsf/WebKeys/BPM-8NUMQD

Regards,